# undefined method `split' for #<Enumerator:0x007fcb41399a90> Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ive bee set the following task and keep getting the error mentioned in the title but cant figure out why. Any help would be great.

```
# Given a sentence, return an array containing every other word.
# Punctuation is not part of the word unless it is a contraction.
# In order to not have to write an actual language parser, there won't be any punctuation too complex.
# There will be no "'" that is not part of a contraction.
# Assume each of these  charactsrs are not to be considered: ! @ $ # % ^ & * ( ) - = _ + [ ] : ; , . / < > ? \ |
#
# Examples
# alternate_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")  # => ["Lorem", "dolor", "amet"]
# alternate_words("Can't we all get along?")      # => ["Can't", "all", "along"]
# alternate_words("Elementary, my dear Watson!")  # => ["Elementary", "dear"]

def alternate_words(string)

   no_p = string.gsub(/[^a-z ^A-Z ^0-9 ']/)
   new_words = []

   no_p.split.each.with_index {|x,i| new_words << string[i] if i.even? }

   new_words
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`no_p = string.gsub(/[^a-z ^A-Z ^0-9 ']/)` you are not using `gsub` correctly. What are the replacement chars? See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub. If you do not provide a replacement then gsub returns an Enumerator object.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. i was hoping that gsub would keep all the letters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and " ' " but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

[String.gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) returns an Enumerator when passed only a single argument. You need to specify a replacement or block for that method to return a String. `split` is a method on String, not on Enumerator, hence your error.